# Is there any tool that gives separate root word and affixes form a given word input?

Tags: nlp, affix

I am searching for a tool that gives me output as follows for the input word 'unstoppable'.

prefix: un
suffix: able
root: stop

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is an [morphological analyzer](https://www.quora.com/In-simple-terms-what-is-a-morphological-analyzer-How-are-they-used-in-machine-translation) that returns "morphemes" of the given word. I'm not sure about the state-of-the-art but [Morfessor FlatCat](http://morpho.aalto.fi/projects/morpho/) should work.

The result is like `straightforwardness` -> `straight/STM + forward/STM + ness/SUF.`

Comment: Thanks, @Limteng I will check it and get back.

Comment: Suggest any other tool if aware of.

Comment: @DaZzLeR I not familiar with morphological analyzers. Google "morphological analysis github" should return many morphological analysis tools.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Lingua Robot](https://www.linguarobot.io). It's a REST API that returns a bunch of useful information for English words including morphemes. Looks like it returns what you want for `unstoppable`:

```
 "morphemes": [
  {
    "entry": "un-",
    "type": "prefix"
  },
  {
    "entry": "stop",
    "type": "root"
  },
  {
    "entry": "-able",
    "type": "suffix"
  }
]
```